# How to add data label value in bar chart in python pivot tabel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

employees = {'Name of Employee': ['Jon','Mark','Tina','Maria','Bill','Jon','Mark','Tina','Maria','Bill','Jon','Mark','Tina','Maria','Bill','Jon','Mark','Tina','Maria','Bill'],
             'Sales': [1000,300,400,500,800,1000,500,700,50,60,1000,900,750,200,300,1000,900,250,750,50],
             'Quarter': [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4],
             'Country': ['US','Japan','Brazil','UK','US','Brazil','Japan','Brazil','US','US','US','Japan','Brazil','UK','Brazil','Japan','Japan','Brazil','UK','US']
            }

df = pd.DataFrame(employees, columns= ['Name of Employee','Sales','Quarter','Country'])

print (df)

pivot = df.pivot_table(index = ['Country'] , values = ['Sales'], aggfunc = 'sum').plot.bar()

         plt.xlabel('Countries')
         plt.ylabel('Sales')
         plt.title('Sales by Countries')

         plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
pivot = df.pivot_table(index = ['Country'] , values = ['Sales'], aggfunc = 'sum')
pivot.plot.bar()

for i in range(4):
    plt.text(i-0.1, 1000, pivot['Sales'].iloc[i], c='w')

plt.xlabel('Countries')
plt.ylabel('Sales')
plt.title('Sales by Countries')

plt.show()
```

There may be a better way to write it than this.[image]